# How to use both Hibernate and Javafx in project?

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx

How to use Javafx and Hibernate in one project? Does anyone have an example with that? It will be very helpful. It's necessary for me to understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I'd hop on github and search for projects that have both javafx and hibernate in it.

[https://github.com/search?q=javafx+Hibernate&type=Repositories&ref=advsearch&l=&l=](https://github.com/search?q=javafx%20Hibernate&type=Repositories&ref=advsearch&l=&l=)

There is this one project here, that seems to be a boilerplate example for the two.

https://github.com/No3x/javafx-boilerplate-hibernate